# 'Execution failed: Data storage error' on setProperty

Tags: google-apps-script

On a script which has been working fine for some time and unchanged, today I get

> 'Execution failed: Data storage error'

on a line which consists simply of:

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('runMode', 'LIVE');
```

What can I do to fix this? 
**Is this some kind of server error?**

Comment: I just started getting this today as well for no reason. I was trying to simply set document properties. Coincidence?

Comment: wait & drink a coffee .. Google has to fix this :/

Answer (score 2):

It's an error from Google. An issue as already been submitted, you can upvote it (click the star in the title) : https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6856

[EDIT] Seems to be up and running now.

Comment: As an aside, some 14 months later, it's happening again :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the google-apps-scripts-issues 6856 describes the problem exactly, as experienced today by dozens of users. Appears to have been fixed at approx 14:00 GMT 24-Mar-17. 
Would like to know whether we need to code around the possibility of a repeat of this error.